# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

Estou com um erro ao executar um código PHP

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp64\www\site\sucessoemail.php on line 35

O código é este

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());


if(isset($_POST['seunome']) && isset($_POST['suasenha']) && empty($_POST['seunome'] ==false) && empty($_POST['suasenha'] == false)){



  $seunome  = $_POST['seunome'];
  $suasenha = $_POST['suasenha'];

$sqli = "CREATE DATABASE" .$_POST['seunome'];

$geral = mysqli_query($sqli) or die("Errro ao criar");

?>
```

Comment: Está certo que o código é esse? Ele diz linha 35 no erro. Se for esse, verifique onde fecha a chave aberta no `IF`.

Answer (score 2):

Falta uma chave no final do código

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());


if(isset($_POST['seunome']) && isset($_POST['suasenha']) && empty($_POST['seunome'] ==false) && empty($_POST['suasenha'] == false)){

  $seunome  = $_POST['seunome'];
  $suasenha = $_POST['suasenha'];
} //Coloquei aqui, mas não sei se deveria ser mais abaixo

$sqli = "CREATE DATABASE" .$_POST['seunome'];    
$geral = mysqli_query($sqli) or die("Errro ao criar");   

?>
```

Comment: essa chave eu ja tentei da o mesmo problema

Comment: Jovem, a chave. Tá comentado no código.

Comment: sim ja coloquei ela antes, da  o mesmo problema.

Comment: Bom, então tá faltando informações na sua pergunta. Provavelmente tá faltando fechar mais chaves. Sem mais detalhes não tem como saber.